# Asking user to select file in Python Script tool using parameter?

Tags: arcpy, csv, python-script-tool, parameters

In a custom toolbox you can make a parameter and ask user for input where he can type something and used as `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` in the script in the toolbox. This is good if you want to use address of a folder but what if needs to select a csv file?

One way would be:

- User types the folder path and the script will add + `file.csv`

Example code:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
file = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

In this case the user will be asked to select a path when using the toolbox.
To do this he just copies the path of the folder the `csv` is. Then he must add manually to the path the: ex. \pop2012.csv.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to select file in parameters in the properties of the toolbox. Then it enables you to select a file.